# How do I clip a circular shape?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `Column` and inside it I am using 7 `Expanded` widgets and one of them is `ClipRRect`, but there is a problem: It is not circle.

I think there are 2 ways:

1. Wrap it with a container and give it's hight value to it's width but I don't know how?
2. Use another widget?

As I use `CachedNetworkImage`, I can't use `CircleAvatar`.

```dart
Expanded(),
Expanded(),
Expanded(),
Expanded(
          flex: 5,
            //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                    child: Text(
                  'tracks',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                )),
                Container(
                  height: 20,
                  width: 20,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: _animationController,
                    child: AspectRatio (
                      aspectRatio: 1,
                      child: ClipOval(
                        //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10000000.0),
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          imageUrl: thisSongInfo.albumImageUrl,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                      return Transform.rotate(
                        child: child,
                        angle: _animationController.value * 2.0 * math.pi,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'information',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
Expanded(),
Expanded(),
Expanded(),
```

I edit and put all code inside that expanded
also I put debugPaintSizeEnabled = true; im main
link:
https://imge.to/i/fU8vi

Comment: can you please add more information or any image, which help you to understand  your problem clearly.

Comment: yes , I edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `ClipRRect` widget with an `AspectRatio` widget with an `aspectRation` value of 1. This forces the child widget to be square.

Or, if suitable, use a `CircleAvatar` widget which displays its child in a circle - this could replace both the `AspectRatio` and the `ClipRRect` widgets.

Edit: This is actually because of the `TabBarView` which **forces** its children to be full width for some reason. Wrap the child of the `TabBarView` within a `Row` so that it's allowed to resize itself horizontally.

Comment: it is amazing to me that why aspect ratio and circleAvatar don't resolve the problem !!!!

Comment: if I change aspecRatio value from 1 to 10 , nothing change !!!but I don't know why?

Comment: Why do you say 'As I use CachedNetworkImage, I can't use CircleAvatar.'? Have you tried it? What was the result? And for AspectRatio I find it hard to believe that that code corresponds to the screenshot below. You couldalso select the `AspectRatio` widget while having the Layout Inspector highlight enabled, and check where it is.

Comment: yes I tried that and the result of using was a Rectangle also I put new image link

Comment: If I remember correctly this is actually because of the `TabBarView` which forces its children to be full width for some reason. Maybe wrapping it with a `Row` could solve the problem? The `Row` itself will be full width but it should allow its children to resize.

Comment: yes , this is because of TabBarView ,thanks so much , wrap it with a row and using widget between 2 expanded , solved the problem

Comment: You can set `mainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.center` on the `Row` and remove the `Expanded` widgets as well.